# $ is not defined in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Let me show you all, i put this code in a file called consultas.php

**CONSULTAS.PHP**

This file shows the table with data, at the end of column called folio `id="'.$row["folio"].'"` when i clicked there this shows me and towards to VISTAPREVIA.PHP for more data about this folio but in paging #1 it works very well and now when i'm going to paging #2 i clicked again and doesn't work because doesn't show me anything, the error says me: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#registros').DataTable({
                "paging": true                
            });
            //new $.fn.dataTable.AutoFill( table );
            $('.back').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();            
                location.reload();
            });

            $('.modificar').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();            
                //Cargamos el contenido del enlace
                var f = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#mainContainer').load(this.href, {folio: f}, function(){                     
                });
            });
            $('.vistaprevia').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();            
                //Cargamos el contenido del enlace
                var f = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#mainContainer').load(this.href, {folio: f}, function(){                     
                });
            });
            $('.detalle').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();
                var f = $(this).attr('id');
                $('<div></div>').load(this.href, {folio: f}).modal();                            
                
            });
        });
    </script>
<a href="#" class="back">REGRESAR ATRÁS</a>
<h1 class="titPer">CONSULTA DE LA TABLA</h1>
<div class="tabla">
    <table id="registros" class="display" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Folio</th>
                <th>Estatus</th>
                <th>Punto de Venta</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>            
            </tr>
        </thead>        
        <tbody>
            <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            ?>
                <tr>                            
                    <td><?=$row['folio']?></td>                
                    <td><?=$row['estatus']?></td>                
                    <td><?=$row['punto_venta']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['usuario']?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            if($_SESSION['permisos'] == 'VENDEDOR' || $_SESSION['permisos'] == 'JEFESUC' || $_SESSION['permisos'] == 'EMBARQUES'){
                                echo '
                                    <center>
                                        <a class="modificar icon-pencil" href="includes/vistaPrevia.php" id="'.$row["folio"].'"></a>
                                         | 
                                        <a class="detalle icon-eye-plus" href="includes/lightbox.php" id="'.$row["folio"].'"></a>
                                    </center>
                                ';                                
                            }else{
                                echo'
                                    <center>                                    
                                        <a class="vistaprevia icon-eye-plus" href="includes/vistaPrevia.php" id="'.$row["folio"].'"></a>
                                    </center>
                                ';
                            }
                        ?>                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>                 
</div>
```

**VISTAPREVIA.PHP**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<a href="includes/consultas.php" class="back">REGRESAR ATRÁS</a>
<h1 class="titPer">ACTUALIZACIÓN DE DATOS</h1>
<!-- <form action="includes/"></form> -->
<?php
    if($_SESSION['permisos'] == 'CALIDAD'){
        include('upRegCal.php');
    }
?>

<form action="includes/edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formAct" method="POST" name="enviarForm">
    <?php
        if($_SESSION['permisos'] == 'VENDEDOR' || $_SESSION['permisos'] == 'JEFESUC' || $_SESSION['permisos'] == 'EMBARQUES'){
            include('upRegUser.php');
        }

        if($_SESSION['permisos'] == 'ADMINISTRADOR'){
            //include('upRegCal.php');
            echo "Hola Administrador";
        }
    ?>    
</form>
```

last

**INDEX.PHP**
i have to assure this part because i put the correct Jquery scripts but i don't know why and i couldn't find the problem and yes i use the Datables Scripts

```
<?php
    session_start();     
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Bienvenido</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>     
        <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/datatables/extensions/AutoFill/js/dataTables.autoFill.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/basic.js'></script>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css"/>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" type="text/css"/>     
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilosForm.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link type='text/css' href='css/basic.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />       
   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/datatables/extensions/AutoFill/css/dataTables.autoFill.css" type="text/css"/>     
        
    </head>
     
    <body>
        <div class="fondoHeader"></div>
        <header class="shadow">
            <nav>       
                <?php                               
                if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
                    include('includes/btnSiSession.php');                   
                else
                    include('includes/btnNoSession.php');                   
                ?>              
            </nav>          
        </header>       
        <div id='mainContainer'>        
            <?php                           
                include('includes/bienvenido.php');             
        
                if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
                    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>"; 
                    // echo "document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'"; 
                    echo "document.getElementById('login').style.visibility='hidden'"; 
                    echo "</script>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>"; 
                    // echo "document.getElementById('login').style.display='block'"; 
                    echo "document.getElementById('login').style.visibility='visible'"; 
                    echo "</script>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <footer> 
            <?php
                include('includes/footer.php');
            ?>    
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
i put this code jQuery CDN script

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#registros').DataTable({
                "paging": true                
            });
            //new $.fn.dataTable.AutoFill( table );
            $('.back').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();            
                location.reload();
            });

            $('.modificar').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();            
                //Cargamos el contenido del enlace
                var f = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#mainContainer').load(this.href, {folio: f}, function(){                     
                });
            });
            $('.vistaprevia').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();            
                //Cargamos el contenido del enlace
                var f = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#mainContainer').load(this.href, {folio: f}, function(){                     
                });
            });
            $('.detalle').on("click", function(event)
            {            
                event.preventDefault();
                var f = $(this).attr('id');
                $('<div></div>').load(this.href, {folio: f}).modal();                            
                
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You have to import jQuery into *every page* that uses it.

Comment: Include jQuery before calling jQuery functions and include it everywhere.

Comment: I did that, but doesn't work too @Pointy because show me the same problem "not defined"

Comment: @Andrew i include too as you say but doesn't work too like same the problem

Comment: @michael yes i think same as you but i had to rewrite the jQuery in only script because i had duplicates jQuery and even so doesn't work

Comment: Look at the page source from the browser. The `<script>` tag for jQuery has to come **before** your JavaScript code that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

In **consultas.php**, you must include JQuery (`<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>`) before using it, before your `<script>`.

In web, each page is different, then you must add jQuery in each one.

### example

```html
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function() {
        /* ... */
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

2nd option: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

After this you can use $ as synonym for jquery.

Comment: This is the solution that also worked by me always!

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you're missing the JQuery library. If you are including your Javascript libraries(including JQuery) at the bottom of your page(footer), you can either

- Include the JQuery library at the top of the page

OR

- make your Javascripts functions into a common js file and include it at the footer just below the Jquery include.

Here is the [link](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) to Jquery CDN

Comment: i put the jQuery CDN scripts, but it shows this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in", even if include the jQuery Library at the top of the page, because the version 1.11.2 it works! instead 1.11.3

Comment: Post the erroneous Javascript here. You can click on the error message (if you're seeing it in the developer tools console) to see what is the cause of the error.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) 
@ vistaPrevia.php:34
<script type="text/javascript">     
     $(document).ready(function() {  <---- here is the error

Comment: Put your jQuery CDN script. This error will be resolved. Then you have posted something about "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator..." in your previous comment. Post more details about that

Comment: [link]http://prntscr.com/7ofmgk here is the caption about this problem

Comment: ;-p Can you please post your source code? At least the JS?

Comment: sorry for the late, i posted my source code including jQuery CDN Script