# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the following error in my Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
```

and this is the code :

```
$(".sb-content-931").owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    baseClass: 'mom-carousel',
    rtl: rtl,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsive: {
        1000: {
            items: 3
        },

        671: {
            items: 3
        },

        480: {
            items: 2
        },

        320: {
            items: 1
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you included  the owlCarousel plugin?

Comment: Pleas heave a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211151/is-not-defined-in-jquery/31211356#31211356 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined. Especially the `$` for `jQuery`... could be a possible answer...Another option is checking for the presence of jQuery itself...

Comment: you didn't load the JS file of owl carousel properly into your DOM. That's the only reason. and some said that jquery may not loaded , if jquery is not loaded, you will not the above error , you will `$ not defined`. so open source and check the JS file of plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add jquery first of all in head section.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also

replace any `$` sign with `jQuery` in your code if you are using wordpress. Wordpress uses `'strict'` mode of Javascript so it is necessary to use `jQuery` instead of `$` only

Answer (score 0):

### This error should be appear based on three criteria

1. Jquery plugin not included.
2. Carousal plugin not included.
3. Above order should not be maintained.